# Entity Framework One To One Relation Adding Entity with code first

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

I have two classes and their relations are as below:

```
public class InteractiveObject
{
     public int Id {get; set;}
     public string Name{ get; set; }

     public int? IndicatorId { get; set; }
     public virtual Indicator Indicator { get; set; }
}

public class Indicator
{
     public int Id {get; set;}
     public string Name{ get; set; }

     public int InteractiveObjectId { get; set; }
     public virtual InteractiveObject InteractiveObject { get; set; }
}
```

And I configure it like

```
  modelBuilder.Entity<Indicator>().HasRequired(x => x.InteractiveObject)
            .WithOptional(x => x.Indicator);
```

It creates two tables that the table Indicator has not a nullable InteractiveObjectId, and table InteractiveObject has a nullable IndicatorId. Perfect.

But when I try to add Indicator with an InteractiveObject. The table Indicator contains the all information but the related InteractiveObject table does not contain IndicatorId. I mean IndicatorId is null on InteractiveObject table but InteractiveObjectId is not null on Indicator table

The code is like below:

```
  modelBuilder.Entity<Indicator>().HasRequired(x => x.InteractiveObject)
            .WithOptional(x => x.Indicator);
```

---

```
        var selectedInteractiveObject = DbContext.Set<InteractiveObject>().FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == 1);

        var indicator = new Indicator { Name = "Test"};

        selectedInteractiveObject.Indicator = indicator;

        DbContext.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: What is primary key in both the entities?

Comment: @JenishRabadiya I have forgotten it while minimizing the code. I edit it now

Comment: By default EF will create foreign keys as Entity_Id. So in your case `InteractiveObjectId_Id`. Did you check if your tables have foreign keys with underscores instead of the expected `InteractiveObjectId`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since we have `one-to-zero or one` relation we don't need to define separate keys as they can share same Id, but `Indicator` refers to `InteractiveObject`. That means that `InteractiveObject` can exist w/o `Indicator` but not vice versa.

So class objects should be like this:

```
 public class Indicator
    {
        [ForeignKey("InteractiveObject")]
        public int Id { get; set; }

        public string Name { get; set; }

        public virtual InteractiveObject InteractiveObject { get; set; }
    }

    public class InteractiveObject
    {

        public int Id { get; set; }

        public string Name { get; set; }

        public virtual Indicator Indicator { get; set; }
    }
```

You should have your context class inherited from `DbContext` like this:

```
public partial class YourContext: DbContext
    {
        static YourContext() { }

        //Class constructor with Connection String name
        public YourContext() : base("name=YourConnectionString") { }

        public DbSet<Indicator> Indicators{ get; set; }
        public DbSet<InteractiveObject> InteractiveObjects { get; set; }
}
```

And now you can operate on its instance via disposable pattern:

```
using (var context = new YourContext())
{
    var selectedInteractiveObject = context.InteractiveObjects.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == 1);
    var indicator = new Indicator { Name = "Test" };
    selectedInteractiveObject.Indicator = indicator;
    context.SaveChanges();
}
```

Comment: When I leave it as it owns, it gives me an error like

Comment: The principal end of this association must be explicitly configured using either the relationship fluent API or data annotations.

Comment: Sorry, I misled you a bit. Since we have `one-to-zero or one` relation we don't need to define separate keys as they can share single Id. So I've updeted my answer.

Comment: Here's your case I think: http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/configure-one-to-one-relationship-in-code-first.aspx

Answer (score 0):

well, You are looking for the value in wrong column.

If you have applied `-Versbose` flag while running migration you would have noticed following SQL statement creating foreign key constraint.

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Indicators] ADD CONSTRAINT [FK_dbo.Indicators_dbo.InteractiveObjects_Id] FOREIGN KEY ([Id]) REFERENCES [dbo].[InteractiveObjects] ([Id])
```

`Id` column of `Indicator` is the foreign key so it would have value pointing to the `ID` of `InteractiveObject`.

**Update**

Making the `Id` of `Indicator` as foreign key also force the constraint that it is one to one or zero relationship while if `IndicatorId` in  `InteractiveObject` would be the foreign key it appeared to be one to zero or many relationship.